# Using Maven dynamic versioning to release a library

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Since Maven 3.5.0, it's possible to use some variables inside the `<version>` tag :
https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Let's say I have `<version>${revision}</version>`, in a library project (it produces a jar to be used in other projects, it's not just a web app or a batch application).

When I build and publish my library v1.0.0 (`mvn deploy -Drevision=1.0.0-release`) the artifact is named "my-library-1.0.0-release.jar", but the pom.xml metadata inside the jar is still at `<version>${revision}</version>`, are there some use cases where this will make my library unusable ?

EDIT : same question if my library is published in a SNAPSHOT repository and used from there as a dependency to other projects.

Comment: Well, an answer may be already in the page I'm quoting : "If you like to install or deploy artifacts by using the above setup you have to use the flatten-maven-plugin otherwise you will install/deploy artifacts in your repository which will not be consumable by Maven anymore."

Comment: Frankly you shouldn't use SNAPSHOT dependencies even for local projects because this make build not reproducible with SNAPSHOTs being overridden.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki So how do you build projects locally? Or don't you do that at all?

Comment: If I'm doing a change across two projects I'd use a SNAPSHOT for the duration of my change. But this is temporary, when I'm done with the change I'd release and "freeze" the version to ensue that `master` branch is stable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be problems with using your library as a dependency and publishing to shared artifact repository (e.g. Maven Central) because your `pom.xml` doesn't match the artifact version. Perhaps some artifact repositories will work (e.g. local Artifactory proxy with custom config) but it's asking for problems.

This is mentioned in the [Maven CI Friendly Versions](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) you linked to, under "Install/Deploy" chapter which suggests to use [flatten-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/):

> If you like to install or deploy artifacts by using the above setup you **have to use** the flatten-maven-plugin otherwise you will install/deploy artifacts in your repository which will not be consumable by Maven anymore.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I read this part later. Do you need to use the flatten-maven-plugin only if you have a parent and/or multi-modules though ?

Comment: I guess it's needed if you have variables in `<version>` tag, regardless of single vs multi-module setup. Best test would be to use `mvn install` and then depend on this artifact from another local project. If it works with local repository you should be fine (there are more gotchas with public repos like Maven Central).

Answer (score -1):

Had this same issue.  Solved with this maven extension (in an extension.xml file):

```
<extensions>
    <!-- this extension ensures ${revision} gets replaced with the proper value in the output pom files-->
    <extension>
      <groupId>fr.jcgay.maven.extension</groupId>
      <artifactId>unique-revision-maven-filtering</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

Comment: Why use yet another plugin/extension when the official [flatten-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/) would solve the problem ?